# How to make an annotation work on every method when it annotated on class, like @ResponseBody

Tags: java, annotations

I want to write an annotation like `@ResponseBody`, use it on class such way that it can work on every method. So I want to know how to implement.

Comment: Please include a code sample.

Comment: To implement this, first of all, you need an annotation processor which will read annotation itself, do you have some?

Comment: I was thinking wrong this afternoon ,now I understand.
The processor get the annotation, I used to think the spring do something to make the class annotation work on method. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

How a class level annotation applies to all methods, is not specific to `@ResponseBody` annotation, it is applicable to all such annotations, `@Transactional` for instance. When compiling code with annotations, the compiler runs the corresponding annotation processor (which has shown interest in that specific annotation). The annotation processor generally uses reflection to inspect the elements being compiled. Processor may simply run checks on the code snippets/methods, modify them, or generate new code before the final compilation. And this might include modification of all methods of that class as well. Refer http://mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example for an example of implementing custom annotations on class level.

***Coming to @ResponseBody:***

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html states that as of spring version 4.0 `@ResponseBody` annotation can also be added on the type level in which case it is inherited and does not need to be added on the method level.

***How @ResponseBody works:***

If you annotate a method (or the encapsulating class) with `@ResponseBody`, spring will try to convert method's return value and write it to the http response automatically.

Depending on your configuration, spring has a list of HttpMessageConverters registered in the background. A HttpMessageConverter's responsibility is to convert the method return value to a HTTP response body, depending on a predefined mime type.

Every time an issued request is hitting a `@ResponseBody` annotation, spring loops through all registered HttpMessageConverters seeking for the first that fits the given mime type and class and then uses it for the actual conversion.

Comment: I mean when I annotate on class,It can work on every method,I want to know how @ResponseBody implement it

Comment: That's my question.
How @ResponseBody implement it

Comment: What you say is clear to me,But I want to write an annotation like ResponseBody,I hope It can work on every method when I annotate on class, So I want to know how ResponseBody implement that.

Comment: You can google for custom annotations on class level. See https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/ for an example. Please accept it as answer if I was able to answer your question

Comment: To be honest, this answer does not solve my problem, but I will give you a vote. Thank you